# Responsiveness of web page using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap.In my website I added some paragraph content and one image,for web its looking fine.But In mobile view I need to display first image below that need to display paragraph.
Can anyone help me to do it?

here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/172cdxto/

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="aboutUsContent" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paddingLeft">
        <h1>ABOUT</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consecteture adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volupat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore feugait nulla facilsi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,cons ectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam eart volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exerci tation ullat.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 truckImg">
        <img src="https://www.rentmerentals.co.nz/assets/Uploads/HT-TRUCK-Isuzu-Elf-Truck-upgraded.png">
      </section>
      <div class="footer">
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="aboutUsContent" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paddingLeft">
        <h1>ABOUT</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consecteture adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volupat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore feugait nulla facilsi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,cons ectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam eart volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exerci tation ullat.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 truckImg">
        <img src="https://www.rentmerentals.co.nz/assets/Uploads/HT-TRUCK-Isuzu-Elf-Truck-upgraded.png" class="img-responsive">
      </section>
      <div class="footer">
          </div>
    </div>
```

You just needed to use `class="img-responsive"` in `img` tag

Comment: ya added.But no changes